# Show that the curve has a point of inflection at $t = 0$ and that the velocity of the moving particle has a maximum at $t = 0$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> If a particle moves in the plane, we may express its coordinates $x$ and $y$ as function of the time $t$. If $x = t^3-t$ and $y = t^4+t$, show that the curve has a point of inflection at $t = 0$ and that the velocity of the moving particle has a maximum at $t = 0$.

**Attempt**

This is just a multivariable calculus question. I can say that the position vector is $\mathbf{r}(t) = (t^3-t)\mathbf{i}+(t^4+t)\mathbf{j}$ and thus its velocity squared is $\left(\dfrac{dx}{dt}\right )^2+\left (\dfrac{dy}{dt} \right )^2 = 16t^6+9t^4+8t^3-6t^2+2$. Thus, taking the derivative of $v^2$ we get $\dfrac{d(v^2)}{dt} = 2v \cdot v' = 96t^5+36t^4+24t^2-12t$. Then I would solve for $v'$ and set it equal to zero.

My book does it a little differently. They take the derivative of $v^2$, not $v$, and claim that it will have the same inflection points? Also what are they doing in the beginning with $x = v \cos(\theta)$ etc.? I just know that the speed is $||\mathbf{v}(t)|| = \sqrt{\left (\dfrac{dx}{dt} \right)^2+\left( \dfrac{dy}{dt} \right)^2}$ and didn't have to do what they did but can someone explain it? FYI this problem was a Putnam question from $70$ years ago.

[image]